# How to check transactiontoolarge exception after upload image in android

Tags: android, exception, compression

I upload image to server then the process still load for long time because got error transactiontoolarge exception in logcat. I know to solve it must do compress image. When compress the JPEG, the quality of image will down. But sometimes i can upload to server without compress. So what i want to do is to check if got transactiontoolarge exception then i will do the compress method. I do try and catch but got error and i don't know exact way to check transctiontoolarge exception. Help me.

Answer (score 2):

TransactionTooLarge exception may be occuring because you are trying to send the complete image via Intent/Broadcast Receiver/Content Provider.

As Intents, Content Providers, Messenger, all system services like Telephone, Vibrator etc. utilize IPC infrastructure provider by Binder and 
**1MB** is the overall limit on all the binder transactions executed in the system at a particular moment.

In case there are lot of transactions happening when the intent is sent,it may fail even though extra data is not large. http://codetheory.in/an-overview-of-android-binder-framework/